# How to get a result based on the different column values in R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
V1  V2  V3
A   0   0
0   A   0
0   A   0
0   A   B
0   0   A
B   B   A
B   B   0
B   0   A
```

Expected result :(Example: If either of the 3 columns contains only A, then result should be 1)

```
A   B   Result
0   0   0
A   0   1
0   B   2
A   B   3
```

The desired output of my dataset should be:

```
V1  V2  V3  Result
A   0   0   1
0   A   0   1
0   A   0   1
0   A   B   3
0   0   A   1
B   B   A   3
B   B   0   2
B   0   A   3
```

Can someone please help me how can we achieve this in R.

Comment: Please add your original data using `dput` function; What happens when there's `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to re-label `c("0","A","B")` as `c("0","1","2")` and then get sum of unique row-wise data using `apply`.

```
df$Result <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
   sum(as.numeric(as.character(factor(unique(x),  levels = c("0","A","B"),
                               labels = c("0", "1", "2")))))
})

#Result

df
#   V1 V2 V3 Result
# 1  0  0  0      0
# 2  A  0  0      1
# 3  0  A  0      1
# 4  0  A  0      1
# 5  0  A  B      3
# 6  0  0  A      1
# 7  B  B  A      3
# 8  B  B  0      2
# 9  B  0  A      3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"V1  V2  V3
0   0   0
A   0   0
0   A   0
0   A   0
0   A   B
0   0   A
B   B   A
B   B   0
B   0   A",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: @slowlearn glad to know. Thanks. You can accept an answer by clicking on tick symbol in left of answer box.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your original data are characters,
so you can probably transform them to a factor and exploit the fact that R maps factors to integers internally.
These factor levels start at 1, so you'll have to adjust the output in the end,
but here's an example of how to do it:

```
# specify the order so that "0"=1L, "A"=2L, "B"=3L
levels <- c("0", "A", "B")

# sample data
df <- expand.grid(levels, levels, levels, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# substitute df with your data frame
columns_list <- lapply(df, function(column) {
  unclass(factor(column, levels = levels)) - 1L
})

foo <- function(...) {
  sum(unique(c(...)))
}

df$Result <- unlist(do.call(Map, c(list(f = foo), columns_list)))

head(df)

  Var1 Var2 Var3 Result
1    0    0    0      0
2    A    0    0      1
3    B    0    0      2
4    0    A    0      1
5    A    A    0      1
6    B    A    0      3
```